# Azure Node.js Web App (Linux) build & deploy issue

Tags: node.js, azure, continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service

I created an Azure web app which will be where my node.js service will be hosted.

Im trying to setup a Node.js app that runs under Linux (not Windows).
Long story short.... the Continuous Delivery (CI) is failing due to errors:'

```
Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Error: Error: Could not find the End of Central Directory Record
```

The build definition looks like this:

```
1. Use Node version (Node Tool installer)
2. npm install
3. Run gulp task (this basically does nothing right now).
```

The release definition looks like this:

```
Tasks -> Phase1 -> Deploy Azure App Service
```

Now, my understanding is that for node.js deployments on a Linux machine, the package should not be zipped. So i removed the zip configuration and simply replaced it with **$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)**

Please help me resolve these CI related errors. I am close to running out of patience with this.

**============= Closed ===============**

```
I finally got my app running (very intuitively might i add) by configuring it on Windows OS (instead of Linux OS). I was really set on having it run on Linux, but it turned out to be a walk thru a mine field.
```